# VK API video.get. Параметр videos

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

В документации сказано, что параметр `videos` принимает список слов, разделенных через запятую. Но, передав ему сначала `list`, а затем `tuple`, он возвращает ответ только на последний указанный идентификатор. Как-же тогда передать список слов, через запятую, да еще и в виде `dict`?

(передаю параметры через опциональное поле `params` в библиотеке `requests`)

upd 1. Я переместил параметр `videos` из `params`, прямо в ссылку.
Как было до:

```
f'https://api.vk.com/method/video.get?v=5.95&access_token={token}',params=({'videos': videos_id,'offset': 0,'count': 100}))
```

Стало:

```
f'https://api.vk.com/method/video.get?videos={videos_id}&v=5.95&access_token={token}',params=({'offset': 0,'count': 100}))
```

Теперь он возвращает:

```
{
"response":
     {
     "count":10,
     "items":[]
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение. Вместо того, чтобы складывать все идентификаторы в `list` или `tuple`, их надо сложить в одну строку (`string`) и если их несколько, то разделить запятой `ПРЯМО В ЭТОЙ-ЖЕ` СТРОКЕ.

Answer (score 0):

**Попробуй так:**
[https://api.vk.com/method/video.МЕТОД?&ПАРАМЕТР=&v=5.95&access_token=ТОКЕН](https://api.vk.com/method/video.%D0%9C%D0%95%D0%A2%D0%9E%D0%94?&%D0%9F%D0%90%D0%A0%D0%90%D0%9C%D0%95%D0%A2%D0%A0=&v=5.95&access_token=%D0%A2%D0%9E%D0%9A%D0%95%D0%9D)
**Пример:**
[https://api.vk.com/method/video.get?&owner_id=92093600&count=1&v=5.95&access_token=ТОКЕН](https://api.vk.com/method/video.get?&owner_id=92093600&count=1&v=5.95&access_token=%D0%A2%D0%9E%D0%9A%D0%95%D0%9D)
**Все методы можешь найти тут:**
https://vk.com/dev/video